# Is apache commons-lang 3.0 available in any maven repo?

Tags: java, maven-2, apache-commons

commons-lang 3.0 is still beta, but can it be found in some maven repository (I couldn't)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the snapshots at http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.0-SNAPSHOT/.

Update: It's been released so it is in the [central maven repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/) now.

Answer (score 14):

Adding repository (POM):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Adding dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Caused the module to be automatically downloaded, but from http://repo.maven.apache.org, not Maven Central